# Ethernet NIC architecture: Function of loopback circuit

Tags: ethernet

[image: Ethernet NIC half-duplex]
<sub>(source: [flylib.com](http://flylib.com/books/1/594/1/html/2/images/f0216.jpg))</sub>

I want to make sure my understanding of the function/the needs of loopback to detect collision is correct.

1. There is frame to transmit from Ethernet controller.
2. TX transmits to wire, loopback and collision detector.
3. RX receives from wire and loopback.
4. RX transmits to collision detector and Ethernet controller.
5. Collision detector compares whether the voltage it receives from TX and RX is same or not.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The SW 127.0.0.1 loopback tests the network stack but not the NIC.
2. The NIC loopback tests the network stack and the NIC card.
3. Cable loopback tests the network stack, the NIC and the connectors.

For the NIC card the loop back is a "mode" of operation, A properly designed NIC would deal with the collision detection appropriately, in full duplex, half duplex etc. situations.

I Think that your second item, "TX transmits to ..." is not right.  I'd say that in loop back the TX transmits only to the RX channel and NOT to the connector/wire as that would defeat the intent of loopback testing.  Likewise for your third item, the RX in loopback would only receive from the TX and not the wire also.

Comment: Does NIC have its own loopback circuit in order to run NIC loopback test? Because I read NIC loopback test requires loopback plug. Is ping to the IP address configured on the NIC equal to NIC loopback test?

Comment: For CSMA/CD, is loopback circuit being used? Or the TX and RX transmit directly to collision detector and the collision detector checks whether the signal from TX is equal to from RX?

Comment: The loopback circuit replaces the loopback plug, allowing for a quick self-test without user interaction, e.g. at system startup.